# docker-compose can't load run.sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that runs a shell script, and has been functioning fine, until all of a sudden it started failing with:

```
ERROR: for pol_app_1  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"run.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"run.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

(I have seen similar questions, but they don't address this specific problem)

The only changes I have been making are to the docker images it uses, but even if I change the image to simply `centos:latest` docker-compose still fails with the errors above.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
  version: '3.5'

  services:
    app:
      image: paulhollyer/phoenix:1.4.9
      ports:
        - 4000:4000
      volumes:
        - .:/app

      depends_on:
        - db

      command: run.sh

    db:
      image: paulhollyer/postgres:12
      command: 'postgres -c "max_connections=200"'
      volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: postgres-data
          target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          volume:
            nocopy: true
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
        POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
        POSTGRES_DB: "pol_dev"

  volumes:
    postgres-data:
```

`run.sh` is next to `docker-compose.yml` in the root of the project.

Does anyone know why `run.sh` can't be found? What could I have done unintentionally to cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must refer to it according to the location it has inside the container. Since the file is in your current host directory and you are adding a volume `.:/app` that would be `/app/run.sh`:

```
command: /app/run.sh
```

Note to avoid weird problems: If `/app` happens to be the `WORKDIR` of the pulled image, `command: ./run.sh` would also work, but be careful with that. For instance, if that's the case, chances are that `/app` already has some files in there, and your mapping would be mounting your current host directory on top of them, making them inaccessible.